# how to post in facebook group that's im member on it using facebook-sdk python

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk

i working in posting in facebook groups app that's are my code but that's only post in the groups im admin on it only are there anyway to post in a group that's im not admin on it using facebook-sdk python lib ?
my code 
import facebook

```
token = "my_acces_token"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
groups = graph.get_object("me/groups")
group_id = groups['data'][2]['id'] # we take the ID of the first group
for post in groups['data']:
        try:
                 graph.put_object(group_id, "feed", message="from terminal")
                 print "liking topic "+ groups['message']

        except:
                continue
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: i want t know are there any way to post in all my facebook groups that im member on it because this code only allow to post in facebook groups that im admin on it :3

Comment: what would you post in the group if you are not admin?

Comment: is it possible that you are trying to post the same predefined message to all groups at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dis Man :D

```
access_token='Access_token'
import facebook 
graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
groups = graph.get_connections(id='me', connection_name='groups')
data = groups['data']
for s in data:
    l = s.values()    
    object_id= l[6]
    try:
        graph.put_object(object_id, 'feed',message="hola")
        print('Done, Posted in %s'%l[1].encode('utf-8',errors='ignore'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

print 'Done, Posted in all groups'
```

Comment: posting the same message to all groups you manage at once would not be allowed - it would be autoposting and prefilling, both not allowed according to the platform policy. and the question was about access to groups you are a member of, not only groups you manage.

Comment: U can use any of public application's access token like HTC or Skype app

Comment: you really should not use those access tokens, only spammers do that and it is definitely illegal. not sure why this is the accepted answer, the question was about getting access to ALL groups, which is not possible anymore. dont try to circumvent stuff with illegal workarounds, it will only get yourself banned.

Comment: He wanna be illegal, it's not ur business

Comment: it is definitely our business. we do not discuss illegal things on stackoverflow, and you should not encourage people to do illegal things.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t get a list of groups you are member of anymore, you can only get groups you manage and you need to use the `user_managed_groups` permission. the `user_groups` permission is gone and there is no replacement.

Comment: what if if have a list of facebook groups ?

Comment: afaik you cannot post to groups you dont manage, at least it should not be possible imho. but you can just try with the api and see what happens ;)

Comment: I tried to post on a group i am a  member of but got below error
`(#200) The user has not authorized the application to perform this action.`

Comment: if you tried with a user token with the publish_actions permission and it still does not work, then i was right and it does not work at all.

Comment: a user can only post in a group in which he is a admin (i think) because i'm able to post pragmatically in a group where i'm an admin

Comment: exactly, that`s how it is supposed to be anyway. allowing every member to post with the api would result in a lot of spam.